# Import and run applications in Eclipse from folders

Tags: eclipse

I'm trying to open files and run applications from folders that are not in the Package Explorer tab. I'm trying by using the File/Import/General/File System... I then select the folder, but the Finish button is still disabled!?

Is this not the correct way or is there a better way to open projects from other placeses than Package Explorer Tab?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go to `File>import>General` - Select `Existing project into workspace` 
Select project folder, uncheck `copy project into workspace` click `finish`. Note: Project must be a valid project.

Answer (score 1):

You can only import a folder which contains Eclipse project specific files like `.project` etc. This way Eclipse knows it is a project.